# Sort list of objects based on a value found in another list of object

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

There are 2 lists of objects *A* and *B*. So `List<A>` and `List<B>`.
*A* and *B* have a common Sting field `id` which connects them.
*B* also has a numeric field `value`.
We want to sort list A based on the `value` present in *list B*.

What's the best way to do it using Java APIs, perhaps like *Comparator*?

Answer (score 5):

I would create a map ranking `id` by `value` for efficient lookup:

```
Map<String, Integer> rank = listB.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.id, b -> b.value));
```

Then you can construct a comparator based on your map and use it to sort the `A` list:

```
listA.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> rank.get(a.id));
```